# Invalid Sytax error for greater than symbol

Tags: python, syntax

For some reason I am getting an invalid sytax error on my greater than symbol.  I just had this code working and something must have changed because now it doesn't.  Trying to figure out why it wont work now.

```
Temp1 = int(input('1 am'))
while Temp1 < -50 or > 130: 
        print('Temperature out of range')
        Temp1 = int(input('Please enter a value between -55 and 130.'))
```

Comment: what you compare with > 130?

Comment: > expects two operands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
Temp1 = int(input('1 am'))
while Temp1 not in range(-50, 131): 
    print('Temperature out of range')
    Temp1 = int(input('Please enter a value between -55 and 130.'))
```

Comment: `range` is exclusive while the OP's code is "inclusive". Your off by one.

Comment: Cmon, it's still working right and I just suggest a different way to that guy consider.

Comment: but your code is logically different than the OP's. It should be `range(-50, 131)`.

Comment: @Li357 you can test by yourself. That code need the input must be <-50 and >130, so it doesn't accept -50 and 130 and my code still right. Can you explain why the end value in `range`  must be 131?

Comment: Because the OP is checking if the value is greater than 130. `range(-50, 130)` gives the sequence [-50, 129], so negating using `not` is equivalent to checking `>= 130`, not `> 130`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Temp1 = int(input('1 am'))
while Temp1 < -50 or Temp1 > 130: 
     print('Temperature out of range')
     Temp1 = int(input('Please enter a value between -55 and 130.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In English we can say "If X is less than 5 or greater than 10", and we understand that X is implied as the first operand for the greater-than operation.

But Python doesn't work that way.  You have to fully spell out each condition:

```
while Temp1 < -50 or Temp1 > 130:
```